# How to avoid interfering namespace issues between the Juce Framework and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, xcode, namespaces, opencv, juce

I created an Juce Audio-Plugin project with the introjucer and Xcode4.
All works fine until I added `#include <cv.h>` into my code.

I got 317 issues in the OpenCV files: core.hpp, operations.hpp, mat.hpp, imgproc.hpp, features2d.hpp, objdetect.hpp that `'juce::Point' is not a type` and some other namespace errors...

I tried to set the `#include <cv.h>` above all other includes and below...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem for the moment: I have added all opencv include instructions at the top of the `PluginEditor.cpp`. But I have a new problem: [Compile issues with OpenCV and Juce on Xcode4.1 in 32bit on Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085759/compile-issues-with-opencv-and-juce-on-xcode4-1-in-32bit-on-lion).