# Compile issues with OpenCV and Juce on Xcode4.1 in 32bit on Lion

Tags: c++, opencv, xcode4.1, juce

I'm trying to compile my VST Plugin with Xcode4.1 in 32Bit. I'm using the Juce Framework and integrated OpenCV 2.2 in it. I installed OpenCV with homebrew and this command:

```
sudo brew install opencv -build32
```

But when I'm compiling the project with Xcode4.1 in 32bit I will get this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_cvLoadImage", referenced from: ...
```

In my Build Settings I have defined the header and library search paths.

```
header search paths: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/include
                     /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/include/opencv
                     /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/include/opencv2

library search paths: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib

other linker flags: -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

But it doesn't compile successful. I hope someone can help me?

Comment: Try this in Terminal: `cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2/lib; file libopencv_highgui.dylib`. What does it say?

Comment: Instead of changing this post to say (solved) in the title, it's probably a better idea to answer your own question with the above information, then accept your answer.  This actually marks the question closed and is the more proper way of saying "d'oh, I answered this myself."

Comment: Okay thanks. I've changed my edit to an own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help of the wiki article section [Using the OpenCV libraries in an Xcode OS X project](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port). Just needed to add the dylib files to my project. :-)

Comment: Hey, I'm glad that helped. I wrote that for Xcode 3. I'm happy to hear it works with Xcode 4 as well.